# python, lxml and xpath - html table parsing

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I 'am new to lxml, quite new to python and could not find a solution to the following:

I need to import a few tables with 3 columns and an undefined number of rows starting at row 3.

When the second column of any row is empty, this row is discarded and the processing of the table is aborted.

The following code prints the table's data fine (but I'm unable to reuse the data afterwards):

```
from lxml.html import parse

def process_row(row):  
    for cell in row.xpath('./td'):  
        print cell.text_content()  
        yield cell.text_content()  

def process_table(table):  
    return [process_row(row) for row in table.xpath('./tr')]

doc = parse(url).getroot()  
tbl = doc.xpath("/html//table[2]")[0]  
data = process_table(tbl)
```

This only prints the first column :(

```
for i in data:  
    print i.next()
```

The following only import the third row, and not the subsequent

```
tbl = doc.xpath("//body/table[2]//tr[position()>2]")[0]
```

Anyone knows a fancy solution to get all the data from row 3 into tbl and copy it into an array so it can be processed into a module with no lxml dependency?

Thanks in advance for your help,  Alex

Comment: Could you paste source document (or part) and expected result? I am not an expert in python, but I am good with xpath and I think I can help you.

Comment: source document is available here (only between 06h00 and 22h00 CET):  
http://tinyurl.com/yj4corh

Comment: expected result:  [['Premier', '05', 'name1'], [u'Deuxi\xe8me', '13', 'name2']]

Answer (score 2):

This is a generator:

```
def process_row(row):  
     for cell in row.xpath('./td'):  
         print cell.text_content()  
         yield cell.text_content()
```

You're calling it as though you thought it returns a list.  It doesn't.  There are contexts in which it *behaves* like a list:

```
print [r for r in process_row(row)]
```

but that's only because a generator and a list both expose the same interface to `for` loops.  Using it in a context where it gets evaluated just one time, e.g.:

```
return [process_row(row) for row in table.xpath('./tr')]
```

just calls a new instance of the generator once for each new value of `row`, returning the first result yielded.

So that's your first problem.  Your second one is that you're expecting:

```
tbl = doc.xpath("//body/table[2]//tr[position()>2]")[0]
```

to give you the third and all subsequent rows, and it's only setting `tbl` to the third row.  Well, the call to `xpath` *is* returning the third and all subsequent rows.  It's the `[0]` at the end that's messing you up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But removing the [0] at the end of the xpath raise the exeption:  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: I do not believe that merely removing the `[0]` from the end of that statement caused that error.  You've changed something else, or the error is being raised later.

Comment: Forgive that poor soul, I have to admit that my python skills are very likely involved... Here is the actual code snippet bugging me: http://pastebin.com/m522b6970

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to access the row's data, like this:

```
for row in data:  
    for col in row:
        print col
```

Calling next() once as you did will access only the first item, which is why you see one column.

Note that due to the nature of generators, you can only access them once. If you changed the call `process_row(row)` into `list(process_row(row))`, the generator would be converted to a list which can be reused.

Update: If you need just the 3rd row and on, use `data[2:]`

Comment: Thanks, the nested loop and adding the list() call indeed did the trick. But it still doesn't work with the second xpath, which is the one I need (I guess)

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you need the second xpath, see the update to my answer.

Comment: I need all the table content starting from row 3, and the second xpath only returns one row. Of course I have done what you have suggested in your update, but I am curious to know what is wrong with the second xpath, as it would make my code for the following days cleaner