# python lxml parsing html

Tags: python, html-table, html-parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse a html document. It contains a couple of tables.
I am able to find the correct table and get data from it using

```
for cell in doc.xpath('//table[@class="CE_13"]')[0]:
    for a in cell:
        print a.text_content()
```

Table consists of 6 columns.
I need only the fifth column. 
Is it possible to get all values in a dict (smth like: `{ column1 : values_of_clm1 ;column2 : values_of_clmn2; .....})` and how? and then read form dict or do you suggest a different solution?

Answer (score 6):

This post could be useful for what you try to do: [python, lxml and xpath - html table parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577487/python-lxml-and-xpath-html-table-parsing).

Then to read your dictionnary you can choose different strategies.
If you know exactly what are the keys then you can access you value directly through the key as such: `my_dict['a_key_string']`

Otherwise you can iterate over you dictionnary as such:

```
for key,val in my_dict.items():
   do_stuff(key,val)
```

**EDIT**

Get all the 5th `td` elements:

```
tds = root.xpath("//table//td[position()=5]")
```

Iterate over the `td` element:

```
for td in tds:
    print "tag %s" % td.tag
    print "inner %s" % td.text
```

Basically you don't need a dictionnary here since you can get directly only the td elements that compose your 5th table column

Comment: but how do I append cell values to dict. with my code I get values not separated (smth like cellValue1Cellvalue2Cellvalue3, etc.). I don't know how to split them and then put them to dict. Splitting them is the biggest problem. Values are of different length

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the following code:

```
en_array = []
for cell in doc.xpath('//table[@class="CE_13"]')[0]:
    for a in cell:
        en_array.append(a.text_content())

print en_array
#Print the 6th column of table
for a,element in enumerate(en_array):
    if a % 9 == 5:
        print en_array[a]
```

If anybody has a better solution please let me know.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the list of cell contents you can use:

```
[c.text for c in doc.xpath('//table[@class="CE_13"][1]//tr/td[5]')]
```

if you really need arbitrary dictionary keys and use Python2.7:

```
l = doc.xpath('//table[@class="CE_13"][1]//tr/td[5]')
{'column%d' % (i+1): l[i].text for i in range(0,len(l))}
```